# How can I use variable from one public function in another public function in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

This is first function in `UsersController`:
And I want to use the `$filename` from this function in another function

```
    public function user(){
        $file = Input::file('image');

        $destinationPath = 'public/uploads/';
        $filename = $file -> getClientOriginalName();

        $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $from = explode('/', $url);

        DB::table('files')->insert(array(
            'filename'=> $filename,
            'file_from'=> $from[1],
            'created_at'=> date('Y-m-d H:m')
        ));

        Input::file('image')->move($destinationPath, $filename);

        return Redirect::to('/user');
    }
```

I want to use `$filename` here. In `from()` function:

```
    public function from(){
        DB::table('from_operator')->insert(array(
            'filename' => $global_filename,
            'category' => Input::get('category'),
            'sign' => Input::get('sign')
        ));
    }
}
```

How can I use it here?

Comment: Where do you call `from()`?

Comment: @lukasgeiter in UsersController

Comment: And in detail? What's the "relationship" between the two functions?  With more information about your case I am able to give a better answer ;)

Comment: @lukasgeiter http://pastebin.com/VVs4fY52 UsersController file here. I want to use the $filename from user() in from()

Answer (score 0):

From your [Pastebin example](http://pastebin.com/VVs4fY52) I can see that you already tried using Sessions. That's definitely the way to go for keeping data over multiple requests (without storing it in a persistent fashion)

**store filename**

```
Session::put('filename', $filename);
```

**retrieve filename**

```
$filename = Session::get('filename');
```

**remove filename from session**

```
Session::forget('filename');
```

Alternatively you can *flash* the filename. That means it will only be in the session for the next request and deleted automatically afterwards. This is useful if you can be sure that `from()` will be the next request after `user()` all the time.

```
Session::flash('filename', $filename);

$filename = Session::get('filename');
```

Comment: It works just for the first time. Now it doesn't works. Error log: filename cannot be NULL. How can I fix it?

Comment: You need it multiple times? I thought only once... Answer updated